# SoundCloud API gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp, soundcloud

In the console it's giving me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ", but if I access direct SoundCloud URL in my browser then it's giving valid JSON. Earlier this code was working fine and today this  issue started.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251912676/?secret_token=s-EkyTy&amp;client_id=08f79801a998c381762ec5b15e4914d5"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>hellooo</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update:

Below is the actual code for which I am asking the question, above html I just created for example.

```
SoundCloud.prototype._jsonp = function (url, callback) {
        var target = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0] || document.head;
        var script = document.createElement('script');

        var id = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
        window[id] = function (data) {
            if (script.parentNode) {
                script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
            }
            window[id] = function () {};
            callback(data);
        };

        script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + id;
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(script, target);
};
```

Comment: Why are you importing a JSON file as a script? JSON is not JavaScript. Did you mean to use JSONP (which is)?

Comment: actually this is part of code we have a custom audio player using react for soundcloud where we were getting JSONP response and everything was working fine but from today onwards error has started.

Comment: Why someone give minus point here, I might not have described well but what is the issue with question, I have callback function in my code.

Comment: We're having the same problem, I think something must have changed in their API...

Answer (score 1):

I got the reason of issue, earlier soundcloud were responding response in jsonp but now they are providing JSON even I passed JsonP callback function. I had to make ajax request to fix it.

I used following code to fix it.

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           callback( JSON.parse(this.responseText) );
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
```

Comment: How did you fix this? I am having the same issue since yesterday.

Comment: I have the same issue, please provide your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but where does this code go? We are simply using the sc-player class for a custom widget. Does this code go in the sc-player.js? And it seems only 70% of our tracks are affected - some play fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The following script tag expects JavaScript code in the source and not JSON.

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to use this externally produced json...

A way to "get" it is using an asynchronous ajax request like `$.get(url,callback);`

Calling it as a script will sure fail...
Because it's not a script.

**Try to run the snippet!**

```js
var url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251912676/?secret_token=s-EkyTy&amp;client_id=08f79801a998c381762ec5b15e4914d5"

var json;

$.get(url,function(result){
    json = result;

    // show in console
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    
    // Now using it...
    $("#json_usage").html(json.tag_list+" and all the "+json.permalink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
 <head>
 <!--script src="https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251912676/?secret_token=s-EkyTy&amp;client_id=08f79801a998c381762ec5b15e4914d5"></script-->
 </head>
 <body>
        <h2>hellooo <span id="json_usage"></span> !</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above, the resulting json is placed in the `json` variable and then console logged.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you've been having trouble with JSONP responses from the SoundCloud API. This was due to a bug that made it into production in the last few days. We've just deployed a fix, and so this endpoint will now be returning valid JSONP responses rather than just JSON, if you specify a `callback` parameter. Sorry for the confusion!