# SoundCloud /resolve API endpoint returns JSON instead of JSONP

Tags: json, jsonp, soundcloud

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194022/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token), Soundcloud recently started returning JSON at `/resolve` instead of JSONP as documented.

Here is a JSBin that demonstrates this issue. IT attempts to resolve a track URL, but the Soundcloud API returns JSON rather than JSONP.

https://jsbin.com/fixabomefe/edit?html,console

(The client ID used there is used in the test environment for an OSS Soundcloud library so it's safe to leak here).

Does anyone (preferably at Soundcloud) know what's going on with the resolve endpoint and jsonp?

Happy to switch to json, but some communication / context about why this change happened would be helpful.

Comment: They seem to have set the appropriate cross origin headers, so you should be able to consume the returned JSON directly, without the JSONP hack necessary.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just trying to understand whether this is intentional on Soundcloud's part, as a lib I'm using uses JSONP, and they told me on Twitter to ask questions about the API on SO. And so before submitting a PR to the lib, I want to understand what Soundcloud's intention is here.

Comment: Having the same problem with our library. Let's just keep writing their support until they can provide a solution! It seems to still be returning jsonp for playlists which makes me think there's an unintentional mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug that made it into production in the last few days. We've just deployed a fix, and it looks like the JSBin is working again. Apologies for the inconvenience!